# difference between proxyMode of @scope annotaion and scopedProxy of context component scan.?

Tags: spring, proxy

is there any difference between proxyMode of @scope annotaion and scopedProxy of context component scan.

I know that latter will enable proxies in all the classes in the specified package value under context component scan.

I just want to know whether there is any functional difference between the two or not or just the former(proxymode of @scope is used to enable proxy on a particular bean)

Comment: can someone please comment on this.Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand the question completely. If you just want to know if there is a difference to the meaning of scope on the annotations, then no, there is no difference

Answer (score 0):

The functionality behind both approaches is the same, according to:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Scope.html